# Javascript using variable as multiple array index

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have this code below, but doesn't work. how i can set a variable as a multiple array index?

```
var tamanho = $(this).html();
var tamanhoNormal = { 
                    'P' : {'A' : 67,'L' : 50},
                    'M' : {'A' : 70,'L' : 52},
                    'G' : {'A' : 72,'L' : 54},
                    'GG' : {'A' : 75,'L' : 58}
                };
alert(tamanhoNormal.tamanho.A);
```

I really don't know how to do it.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing `tamanho` is "P", "M", "G" or "GG", then use

```
alert(tamanhoNormal[tamanho].A);
```

Comment: Thank You so much! You really helped me a lot :D
I'm so newbie !